# Downloading Repository as Zip with Enclosing Folder using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, zip, azure-rest-api

I've been using the Azure DevOps REST API to download repositories as zip files (for use with Conan, the C / C++ package manager.)

I use the following endpoint:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?scopePath=/&recursionLevel=full&includeContentMetadata=false&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=0&versionDescriptor.version={commitOrBranchToDownload}&$format=zip](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/items?scopePath=/&recursionLevel=full&includeContentMetadata=false&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=0&versionDescriptor.version=%7BcommitOrBranchToDownload%7D&$format=zip)

This works well for retrieving the files, but when I extract the zip file, all files are directly in the root **with no enclosing folder**. (This causes problems with Conan, which expects an enclosing folder to appear when extracting the package.)

Is there a way to configure the API call, or any setting in Azure DevOps itself, **to include an enclosing folder in the zip file?** Ideally, this would be a folder with the same name as the repository or branch being downloaded. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require manually creating a folder for each download on the client side.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.